# How can I QuickCheck value wrapped by effect in PureScript?

Tags: quickcheck, purescript

I have a `shuffle` function for `Array`:

```purescript
shuffle:: forall e. Array -> Eff (random :: RANDOM | e) Array
```

It shuffles an array in a `Control.Monad.Eff.Random` monad and returns the wrapped one. I want to test the array is shuffled, like to compare the result is different, so I write QuickCheck code like:

```purescript
quickCheck \arr -> isShuffled (shuffle arr)
```

However, I'm not sure how to write `isShuffled` to match type definitions. Since:

1. There is no unwrapping function like `fromJust` in `Maybe`, so it must accept `Random Array` and return `Random Boolean`, while I put the checking code in the Monadic expression.
2. Therefore, the result of `isShuffled` will not be plain `Boolean`, but like `m Boolean`
3. There is no suitable `Testable` in `purescript-quickcheck` for `m Boolean`, so I may need to create one instance for it, while the comment in QuickCheck refers:

   `A testable property is a function of zero or more Arbitrary arguments, returning a Boolean or Result.` ([code](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-quickcheck/blob/master/src/Test/QuickCheck.purs#L122-L127))
4. However, again, I cannot extract/unwrap a value from `Random` monad, I don't know how to access the boolean inside it and to implement like `testableRandomArray` to have `Boolean` or `Result` from a `Random Boolean`, unless I use some unsafe features.

I think I should "embed" the line of `quickCheck` inside a Random monad so I can access the pure Array it shuffled. However, since it is `quickCheck` to generate the test fixtures, I feel this is weird and no way to do that.